# Unable to create servlet inside package any other than default package

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee

I am trying to learn servlets. Servlets works fine when created in default package but gives error where package is defined.

Following is the error :

```
Multiple markers at this line

- The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
 required .class files

- The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
 required .class files
```

Error is in this line :

```
  package  pack;
```

I am using Eclipse Indigo IDE.
I have tried removing and adding jars again but it still gives same error. Please suggest a solution.
Thank you.

Comment: This looks strange. ObjectInputStream is in the standard runtime and should always be available. Something is wrong with your Eclipse setup. I reckon this is not only due to your servlet being in a non-default package.

Comment: This is not the problem with other j2ee projects. They are having servlets inside packages other than default one and are working fine.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with that project.